# Как заставить shell выполнить командный файл не порождая новый процесс?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Объясните пожалуйста, как это можно сделать для sh и csh.

Comment: `source`, он же `.`

Comment: @Fat-Zer можно пожалуйста поподробнее, с примером. Этот метод используется одинаково для sh и csh?

Comment: `source /path/to/script`, подробностей особых нет... на счёт csh — не подскажу... кроме того, это по факту исполнение команд из скрипта в контексте текущей оболочки... А если сам скрипт порождает subshel'ы или `fork`/`exec`'ается, то это понятно так и останется... собственно какова цель вопроса?

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо, цель вопроса - узнать, как выполнить скрипт без создания нового процесса в указанных оболочках.

Comment: странная самоцель... но у всех свои фетиши =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[стандартом *posix* определена](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) (для совместимых со стандартом оболочек) [встроенная команда «точка»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)) (<kbd>.</kbd>):

```
. файл
```

оболочка должна выполнить команды из указанного файла в текущем окружении (т.е., не порождая нового процесса оболочки для интерпретации файла).

---

во многих реализациях posix-совместимых оболочек (например, в [*gnu/bash*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)) присутствует ещё [синоним этой команды — `source`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)):

```
source файл
```

а некоторые оболочки (например, [*csh*](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/04.csh/paper-2.html#section19)), наоборот, имеют встоенную команду `source`, но не понимают команды «точка» (тем самым подтверждая свою несовместимость со стандартом *posix*).

---

поэтому абсолютно правильный ответ на вопрос должен звучать примерно так:

одной универсальной командой это сделать невозможно (т.е., одновременно и для программы *csh* и для совместимой со стандартом posix оболочки). надо проверять наличие встроенных команд `.` либо `source` (с помощью, например, программ [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) или [`type`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html), либо их встроенных в оболочку аналогов), и выполнять ту, которую понимает используемая оболочка.