# Что всё-таки означает загадочный символ . в bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Почему символ `.` в зависимости от контекста выполняет разные задачи? Например в команде `cd .` он выполняет роль текущей директории, а в команде `. patch/activate` является аналогом команды `source`?

P.S наверное я дилетант, но это действительно ломает мне мозг

Comment: Очевидно, в первой позиции он означает выполняемую команду, а в любой другой позиции просто аргумент для команды. Это касается любой последовательности символов, не только точки, тот же `cd cd` перейдёт в каталог с именем cd, если такой существует :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ни тот ни другой случай употребления не имеет прямого отношения к программе *bash* как таковой.

- `cd` — это [определяемая стандартом posix утилита](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), которая вызывается как `cd каталог` и служит для изменения текущего каталога для процесса оболочки, её вызвавшего (все популярные posix-совместимые оболочки реализуют её как встроенную команду). в каждом (даже «пустом») каталоге есть как минимум два компонента (в терминах стандарта posix — *entries*): [`.`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_136) и [`..`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_137). первый из них (`.`) — это ссылка на сам каталог, а второй (`..`) — это ссылка на «родительский» (т.е., предшествующий в файловой иерархии) каталог.

  поэтому команда `cd .` означает: «сменить текущий каталог на него же самого», т.е., фактически, не производит никаких изменений.
- `.` — это [встроенная команда posix-совместимой оболочки](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot), вызываемая как `. файл` и служащая для выполнения команд, содержащихся в файле, в контексте текущего процесса оболочки. подробнее см. [ответ на соответствующий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803001/178576).

Comment: *cd .* как минимум меняет значение *$OLD_PWD*, если я правильно помню её имя.