# Добавление environment переменной из bash

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, bash, shell

Никак немогу заставить скрипт добавлять переменную окружения в Ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(lsmod | grep nouveau)" > /dev/null ]
then
export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1
echo "test"

fi
```

Если вручную писать в терминале

```
export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1
```

все работает как нужно, и от юзера и от рута. Но скрипт не добавляет переменную даже при ручном запуске, вывод

```
env
```

не содержит нужную переменную. Пробовал делать:

```
export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL="1"
```

Но ничего не меняется. Права на скрипт 777.
Жестко добавить в /etc/environment не могу в силу определенных причин, так как сборка конфигурируется под разное железо и если использовать переменную export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL там где не используются драйверы nouveau то софт приложение будет падать.

Comment: `if [ "$(lsmod | grep nouveau)" > /dev/null ]` - что у вас эта строчка значит, можете словами описать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что bash создает а при выходе из скрипта уничтожает  копию environment
запустите `. вашскрит.sh` и все получится.
PS: здесь похожий [вопрос](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019600/cannot-set-an-environment-variable-using-a-bash-script)

Comment: Я читал про это. Пробовал запускать как source ./script.sh и все равно корректно не работало. Как решу проблему, отпишу.

Comment: может надо функцию в .bashrc типа `nouveau (){
    if  [ "echo 1" ] 
#у меня еcho типа как тру
then
export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1
echo "test"

fi`

[похоже здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Вместо скрипта выполните:

```
$ export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=$(lsmod | grep -cm1 ^nouveau)
```

Значение переменной будет 1 - если модуль `nouveau` загружен, 0 - в противном случае.

Ситуация в вопросе неплохо описана, [например, здесь](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch06_02.htm), процитирую:

> Sooner or later, almost everyone writes a shell script that gathers some information, sets a few environment variables, and quits. The writer then wonders why there's no trace of the "new" environment variables to be found. The problem is simple. A UNIX process cannot change its parent's environment; a UNIX process gets its own copy of the parent's environment, and any changes it makes it keeps to itself. A process can make changes and pass them to its children, but there's no way of going in reverse.
>   (*You can't teach an old dog new tricks.*)

Смысл цитаты:

Рано или поздно, почти все пытаются написать скрипт, который собирает некоторую информацию, устанавливает переменные окружения и завершает работу. Автор скрипта удивляется, почему эти новые переменные исчезли бесследно. UNIX процесс не может изменить окружение своего процесса-родителя; UNIX процесс получает копию окружения своего родителя и все изменения окружения в процессе-наследнике остаются только в нём.
(*Яйца курицу не учат.*)

Comment: Ваш код не меняет сути. Мне нужно задать автоматизацию данного процесса при запуске сессии пользователя. Все дело в наследовании системных процессах(предполагаю), в которых работает мое приложение, может быть даже в уровнях исполнения.

Comment: Какой сути? Никакой сути я не собирался менять. Это только прямой ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Мне нужно не что-то выполнять вручную, а чтобы при запуске система автоматически конфигурировалась, в данном случае добавлялась или нет переменная окружения в зависимости от подгруженного модуля. Автоматически, без вмешательства пользователя. Так как их будет несколько сотен.

Comment: Всё правильно. Ничего вручную я не предлогал выполнять.  `. вашскрит.sh` в принятом вами ответе, и строка в моём ответе - это одно и тоже. Я только переписал ваш скрипт из вопроса в одну строку.

Comment: Благодарю за указание направления(действительно по началу выглядит все не очень наглядно пока не начнешь углубляться) и за помощь в понятии синтаксиса баша. Буду пробовать и думаю что обязательно все получится.

Comment: Рад, что помог. В любом случае, переработайте строку кода, на которую я указал в комментарии под вопросом. Она крайне неграмотно написана, хотя и выглядит, что работает.  Например так: `if lsmod | grep ^nouveau >/dev/null; then ...`

Answer (score 3):

1. переменные окружения — это свойство каждого процесса.
2. по умолчанию дочерний процесс наследует все переменные окружения родительского.
3. в процессе работы процесс может изменить **свои** переменные окружения.
4. повлиять на переменные родительского процесса дочерний, конечно же, **не может**.

выполняя скрипт, вы порождаете новый процесс. он получает свой набор переменных окружения и может манипулировать им как угодно.

у оболочки есть возможность выполнить скрипт «особым образом», без порождения нового процесса оболочки: [`. файл` или `source файл`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803001/178576). все манипуляции с переменными окружения внутри таким образом выполняемого скрипта будут относиться к текущему процессу оболочки.

Comment: Да, я понимаю принципы ООП и в данном случае здесь нечто extend наследования. Буду пробовать дальше в этом духе пробовать разные решения, благодарю за подробное разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Первое.

Конструкция `lsmod | grep` - работает, но ....

Для скриптов есть специальная штука **modinfo**:

```
#!/bin/bash

modinfo nouveau >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq "0" ]
then
    echo "module present"
else
    echo "module not present"
fi
```

Второе.

Зачем проблему определения наличия модуля в системе решать через переменную окружения, к тому же не прибегая к system-wide настройкам, а пытаясь как-то "запихать" ее (куда-то) из скрипта, временно запущенного в сеансе какого-то юзера?

Почему задачу определения модуля не возложить на конфигуратор приложения...

> так как сборка конфигурируется под разное железо

?

Comment: Задача немного другая. Мне нужно определить какой модуль загружен и если загружен nouveau, то добавлять переменную окружения export QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1, если незагружен, то ничего не делать. И да, это нужно делать для сеанса юзера, так как корень самой системы для всех один и расшарен по NFS, и как раз поэтому я не могу добавить жестко /etc/environment, делаю это костылем. На счет приложения, нет возможности переписать приложение. Нужно запустить то что есть, используя небольшой костылик в виде

Comment: QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1. Благодарю за ответ. Я добавлял скрипт автозагрузки в /.config/autostart и в секцию Exec добавлял Exec=. ./script.sh, содержание которого приведено выше. Я проверяю что скрипт реально запускается и отрабатывает, так как добавил в нем строчку echo "testStart" >myLog но сама переменная окружения не добавляется. Вот это и странно.

Comment: Добавлю, что я хочу решить известную на багзилле проблему работы WebEngite QT с драйверами nouveau(проблема рендеринга). Но рабочие машины у меня на разном железе, где то будет nouveau, где-то i915.