# BASH. Python не активируется виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, bash

Хочу создать скрипт который будет создавать и активировать виртуальное окружение на Python. С первой частью всё в порядке. Вот скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Название проекта" 
read name
mkdir $name
cd $name
python -m venv v
source v/bin/activate
```

Не работает именно последняя строчка которая отвечает за активацию окружения.
**source v/bin/activate**
В терминале не показывается значок активации виртуального окружения. ОС: Mac OS.
Все остальные папки окружения успешно создаются

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что она работает, но интерпретатор делает новый экземпляр себя на исполнение скрипта, поэтому мы не видим результат после выполнения потому что этот экземпляр /bin/bash уничтожится

Comment: У меня тоже есть такое подозрение потому что никаких ошибок не выходило

Comment: В крайнем случае можно это проверить путем запуска скрипта прямо после `source v/bin/activate `, ну и чтобы пакеты в общем окружении нужные не стояли

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819137/178576) , [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458278/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь! aleksandr barakin ваша ссылка помогла мне. Вообщем нужно просто скрипт запустить с командой source. В моём случае это выглядит так: source t1

Answer (score 4):

Перед скриптом в терминале необходимо указать команду `source`.

```
source название вашего скрипта
```