# запись данных из конфиг файла в переменные bash

Tags: bash

Мне требуется написать скрипт, но для его работы нужна подгрузка данных из конфига.

У меня есть файл data.config в котором хранятся данные для авторизации

```
login=admin
password=1234
```

В bash скрипте хочу иметь переменные `login` и `password` которые будут равны тому, что написано в конфиге

Comment: `source /.../data.config` или `. /.../data.config` вначале скрипта решат вашу проблему

Comment: Да, правда. Помогло, спасибо

Comment: @PotroNik, `source` непереносимо, к сожалению. Правильно `. .../data.config`, как указано в вашем комментарии.

Comment: @0andriy о, а это интересно, всегда считал что это одна и та же команда, а есть источник, где можно прочитать подробности? Спасибо

Comment: @PotroNik, да много где, например, стандарт не описывает `source`, а только `.`. Также есть сравнительная табличка на Bash Wiki: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/nonportable. Ну и полно вопросов-ответов на эту тему, как https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/what-is-the-difference-between-and-source-in-shells, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour или https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

приведённое вами содержимое файла выглядит как полноценный скрипт оболочки.

значит, его можно интерпретировать. причём, [чтобы результаты интерпретации были доступны текущему процессу, надо использовать оператор `.`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803001/178576) или его псевдоним `source`, доступный, например, в программе *gnu/bash*:

```
. файл
```

или

```
source файл
```